# LWUIT focus issue

Tags: focus, lwuit

I have created a screen in lwuit which has focus issue. The screen is like a list screen in which each component have a profile pic at the left and a text in the middle. Each component is a container in which I have placed a button for profile pic and text area for text. All are non-focusable except the component itself. When focus comes to the component, I want to highlight the component. It works fine when the text is small. But when the text exceed the screen height, the focus is not coming to next component, scrolling is not smooth and focus does not come to next component, though scrolling continues.

What am I doing wrong. Checked fb j2me app with similar ui and it works fine.

Comment: can you share some code of your list render?

Comment: you can use lwuit controller to make ui as u want. whatever backgrounds and selected effects you want to give ur app, you can make.

Comment: Yes, this this works best, DeepSan

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the UI to focus based scrolling in the look and feel class. Alternatively you can define `setNextFocusDown()` for the specific component which sometimes helps. We fixed some issues related to focus in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) so this might be one of those LWUIT bugs with focus for which there is no workaround.